# Python: Program doesn't return data until it's ran twice

Tags: python-3.x

When data is entered the first time it doesn't run the calc function it just resets from main(). Once data is entered a second time the data is inputed into the calc function. I would really appreciate the help!

```
def main():
    numbers = get_val()
    get_calc(numbers)

def get_val():
    print("Please enter 10 numbers:")
    values = []
    for i in range(10):
        value = int(input("Enter a number:"))
        values.append(value)
    return values

def get_calc(numbers):
    list1 = get_val()
    print(list1)
    print("The lowest number is", min(numbers))
    print("The highest number is", max(numbers))
    print("The sum of the numbers is", sum(numbers))
    print("The average of the numbers is", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `get_val()` twice. First time, you call it in `main()`:

```
def main():
    numbers = get_val()
```

Second time you're calling it in `get_calc()`:

```
def get_calc(numbers):
    list1 = get_val()
    print(list1)
    ...
```

This means that once you call main, it computes `numbers` and passes it into `get_calc()`. However, in `get_calc()` you also compute another list of numbers: `list1`. You print it, and then go on working with `numbers`.

It should be:

```
def main():
    numbers = get_val()
    get_calc(numbers)

def get_val():
    print("Please enter 10 numbers:")
    values = []
    for i in range(10):
        value = int(input("Enter a number:"))
        values.append(value)
    return values

def get_calc(numbers):
    print(numbers)
    print("The lowest number is", min(numbers))
    print("The highest number is", max(numbers))
    print("The sum of the numbers is", sum(numbers))
    print("The average of the numbers is", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
main()
```

Comment: Oh, duh, I don't know why I was redefining a new variable. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! If it solved your problem, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your get_calc function, you ask user to get numbers one more.

`def get_calc(numbers):
    list1 = numbers #I think this is what you want.
    print(list1)
    print("The lowest number is", min(numbers))
    print("The highest number is", max(numbers))
    print("The sum of the numbers is", sum(numbers))
    print("The average of the numbers is", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))`